# excel replace string in formula

Tags: excel

Using Excel 2010, I have a sheet filled with "almost" the same formula. I need to replace all instances from `=COUNTIFS` to `=1-(COUNTIFS` and then the last `)` needs replaced with `))`

Trying to use CTRL+H gives errors that the formula is missing a `)`

Anyother smart way to get this done?

Comment: This might help: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/47069-replace-text-within-formula.html

Comment: It gave a hint. But even though - it still gives same error. Perhaps replacing the last ) with )) to begin with.. and then replacing the =countifs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way if you're using Excel 2013 or newer.

1. Use `FORMULATEXT()` function to modify your formulae, like this: `="1-("&FORMULATEXT(A1)&")"`.
2. Copy and paste the results of this **as values.**
3. Now you have correct formulae as text. To force their evaluation simply select them and replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) `=` for `=`. This way formulae are not changed but forced to re-evaluate.